# Do Illusory Creatures suffer Multiple Attack Penalty (MAP); is it shared with the spellcaster?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, multiple-attack-penalty

[*Illusory creature*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=158) isn't a Minion and doesn't provide much information about attacking. It seems likely that it would take MAP, but doesn't specify so I'm not sure; it's additionally unclear if it shares MAP with the spellcaster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Multiple Attack Penalty](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=322) is something that typically only applies to the individual creature making the attack, and is impacted by every check with the attack trait. Since *illusory creatures* can make Strikes, they would suffer the MAP as any other creature.

> **The more attacks you make beyond your first in a single turn, the less accurate you become**, represented by the multiple attack penalty. The second time you use an attack action during your turn, you take a –5 penalty to your attack roll. The third time you attack, and on any subsequent attacks, you take a –10 penalty to your attack roll. **Every check that has the attack trait counts toward your multiple attack penalty, including Strikes**, spell attack rolls, certain skill actions like Shove, and many others.

There is one oddity under [Mounted Combat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=464) where different creatures would share a MAP, though it would likely be difficult to ride an illusion.

> You and your mount fight as a unit. Consequently, you share a multiple attack penalty. For example, if you Strike and then Command an Animal to have your mount Strike, your mount’s attack takes a –5 multiple attack penalty.

Comment: Yeah, I think the default is that every creature has their own MAP, and it's not required to be stated. If they share MAP or don't have MAP, that's the exception to the rule and thus needs to be called out.

Comment: I wasn't sure since it uses your spellcasting attack modifier and most spells which do so give MAP to the spellcaster (because it's the spellcaster making the attack).